# Why do we swap the position in the cycle when writing disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I was watching a [video on tranpositions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LVdaKQzM4U#t=2m39s) and it isn't obvious to me why when decomposing a cycle, we swap the position of the elements in the cycle instead of swapping the elements themselves. I would like if someone could explain to me what is really going on when we do these transpositions.

So for instance, to write $(4, 1, 2, 3)$ as a disjoint transpositions, one could do (the textbook way):

$$(4, 3)(4, 2)(4, 1)$$

while we could also do $$(3, 4)(2,3)(1,2)$$

as in the video. Note that I flipped the order because I calculate transpositions from right to left. So my convention is I evaluate $(1,2)$, then $(2,3)$, and finally $(3,4)$.

In the video I linked (I already timed it exactly, so you won't have to skip), he drew this matrix thing I have never seen before in any textbook.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2  &3  &4 \\ 
 1&2  &4  &3 \\ 
1 &4  &2  &3 \\ 
 4&1  &2  &3 
\end{pmatrix}$$

To my understanding, he swapped $4$ and $3$ initially, and then swapped $4,2$ in the middle, but he writes $(2, 3)$ indicating he is only swapping the positions, not permutation the elements. Can someone formally write out what is going on here?

For instance, I tried formalizing and conjecturing that he is multiplying $(1, 2,3,4)(3,4)$ and then keep decomposing, and obviously I was wrong.

Comment: You should include the [tag:group-theory] tag in your questions. It will help them to be seen by more people.

Comment: I thought group theory is part of algebra.

Comment: It is, but the tags are a method of labelling questions which people use to find relevant questions. For example, I haunt the group theory tag but *not* the abstract algebra tag as the latter is full of questions about rings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my eyes the matrix represents exactly the same operations that you wrote down in cycle notation: the 2nd line of the matrix indicates that the two numbers at the positions 3 and 4 are swapped - (3,4) in cycle notation. Next in the 3rd line the two numbers at the position 2 and 3 are swapped - (2,3). In last line the numbers at the positions 1 and are swapped - (1,2). Altogether $(1,2)(2,3)(3,4)$, which is correct.

Remark: you are talking about disjoint decomposition into transpositions. But all the decompositions appearing are not disjoint. In fact a cycle can only be decomposed into disjoint transpositons if it is already a transposition.